# IOS: App-Language independent of device without changing NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, localization, nslocale

I use the following statement to change the application language (independent of the system language):

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"de", @"en", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

In a different situation I want to get the system language. When I use

```
[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0]
```

the result is *always* "de". Even when the App is restarted and the second statement is executed first.
This makes perfect sense to me since this is what I just configured with the code line above.
However I would like to get the actual system language that was configured system wide.

Rationale:
Application should have three language settings: English, German, System Language. The user should be able to run the app in english while the rest of the system runs in german or alternatively just use the standard system language setting.

I would really appreciate some help here:)
Best regards,
Jonathan

---

I finally found an easy and robust solution. The initial problem was that

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"de", @"en", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

returns the values I configured before. But that is not what I want to have. I want to have the language that is configured "globally" (independent of the application/used in menus and so on). This does not seem to be achievable by NSUserDefaults. CFPreferences however does the trick:

```
CFPropertyListRef propertyList = CFPreferencesCopyValue(CFSTR("AppleLanguages"),
    kCFPreferencesAnyApplication, kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, kCFPreferencesCurrentHost);
NSArray *appleLanguages = (__bridge_transfer NSArray*)propertyList;
```

appleLanguages now contains a list of languages as they are originally defined for the user. And appleLanguages[0] is just what I wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the `de` language as the object at index:0 here: `[NSArrray arrayWithObjects: @"de", @"en", nil]`. When you check what the preferred languages are here, you only check what the first language is (the language at index 0), but there are languages at other indices too (you set "en" to be at index 1): `[[NSLocale preferredLanguages]objectAtIndex:0];`. Let's say you want to store the preferred languages in an array; you could do this:

```
NSArray *arrayOfLanguages = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[NSUserDefaults arrayForKey:@"AppleLanguages"]];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Jona I'm not really proposing to store the languages in an array; I was just giving an example of how you should properly access the language data. You could store it in an array and put the code in the App Delegate in the `finishedLaunching:WithOptions` method. This would make the app check for the languages every time it restarted.